# javascript works locally but not in live server

Tags: javascript, html

I am going crazy because of this and google has givin me no answer at all. i have a code containing javascript, and i am perfectly able to execute it locally, but not at all in live server. here is part of the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
 <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <link href="layout.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="./jquery.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="./jquery.flot.js"></script>
 </head>
```

and the javascript libraries are in the right location, same file as the javascript code.
any answer would be appreciated. thanks !

i just tried it again and here are the errors from the console:

SCRIPT1002: Syntax error 
jquery.js, line 1 character 1

SCRIPT1002: Syntax error 
jquery.flot.js, line 1 character 1

Comment: What does the console say? Any 404s?

Comment: I think those files are not in the right place..

Comment: Open up firebug and then click console. You'll probably get a `404` for these files

Comment: there also might be happen your above java-script load sucessfully but, possible to have error in your javascript-jquery functions ..you can not justify like ***if my javscript code not work that means jquery not included into my pag***

Comment: After your edits, it looks like something's wrong with your .js files. Could you upload the html and the js files into [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), if they are not private?

Answer (score 1):

Try it without the `./` if the are in the same location they should be found without the `./`, otherwise i would check where do ou have them localy else than in the same folder as on the server.